# Allowtransparency iframe comparability

Tags: html, iframe

What compatibility issues does the allow transparency in iframe have?
Which browsers and which browsers do not support this?

So far i have tested in IE 10 and Chrome 30

Answer (score 0):

There are no compatibility issues between browsers for the allow transparency. Tested and worked, ill advised.